# paint image x times in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, paint

I am working on making my world and I have all my x coords in an array and would like to use a for loop to paint it to the screen. It would hold 27 values but, my problem is I don't know what I would fill the rest of my parameters with.

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g2d){
    for(int i = 0; i < blockPlacementX; i++){
        g2d.drawImage(getBlockIMG(), , ,null); //img, x, y, null
    }
}
```

full class

```
package com.questkings.game;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class MapLayout {

int[] blockPlacementX = {0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300,
        330, 360, 390, 420, 450, 480, 510, 540, 570, 600, 630, 660, 690, 720,
        750, 780, 810};

int[] blockPlacementY = { };

private Game game;

public MapLayout(Game game){
    this.game=game;
}

//Map size 800(x), 400(y)

public void paint(Graphics2D g2d){
    for(int i = 0; i < blockPlacementX; i++){
        g2d.drawImage(getBlockIMG());
    }
}

public Image getBlockIMG(){
    ImageIcon ic = new  ImageIcon("C:/Users/AncientPandas/Desktop/QuestKings/Misc/Images/Sprites/grassWall.png");
    return ic.getImage();
}

public Rectangle getBoundsBlock(){
    return new Rectangle(0, 345, 810, 1);
}

}
```

So I tried, but it draws it really quick then it disappears. Any ideas?

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g2d){
    for(int i = 0; i < blockPlacementX[27]; i++){
        g2d.drawImage(getBlockIMG(), blockPlacementX[0]++, blockPlacementY [0], null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to obtain a 2D image using only "x" coordinates ? In this case you will obtain only a line, considering a default value for "y".

Comment: I do have an array for my y position also only one value atm though. For y position 344. I'm just not really sure what my x and y parameters should be for g2d.drawImage(getBlockIMG()); because I am reading from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but are you trying to tile a given set (or a single set) of images along the x-axis using a predefined array of co-ordinates.

If you have two arrays of X and Y co-ordinates (of equal length), a simple iteration through the array would do the trick as below:

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g2d){
    for(int i = 0; i < blockPlacementX.length; i++){
        g2d.drawImage(getBlockIMG(), blockPlacementX[i], blockPlacementY[i], null);
    }
}
```

If you had a single Y co-ordinate, you simply replace `blockPlacementY[i]` with the variable containing the Y co-ordinate.

If you have differing lengths of X and Y co-ordinate arrays, you need to figure out how to assign co-ordinates to each image based on some rule set.